# Problems running the ccny_rgbd package

Tags: ros, ccny-rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get ccny_rgbd working on a turtlebot.  It seems to be kind of working but I think it's still not quite working as  it should.

On the turtlebot I launch:

```
roslaunch ccny_openni_launch openni.launch publish_cloud:=true
```

I get a complaint in the terminal about a missing camera calibration file but it still seems to run anyway.

Then on the workstation I launch:

```
roslaunch ccny_rgbd vo+mapping.launch
```

I run the corresponding rViz config file.  At this point I did get a rgbd image in rViz but it takes a very long time, several minutes.  I left it running for a while and it did update the rgbd image but the update rate was very slow.  Again several minutes per image.  Other times it doesn't give me the rgbd image at all after waiting up to 10min.  I'm sure this isn't normal but I'm not really sure where to ever start at trying to fix it.  Maybe my computer is just too slow for this?

I also tried to record a bag file to try and process the data later but ran into a problem with the TF data being old.  Not sure what's going on there either.  It seems to run fine when I'm not trying to record the bag file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57661/problems-running-the-ccny_rgbd-package/) by [jd](https://answers.ros.org/users/2939/jd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2013-03-10**:
Can you post information about your setup? What's your processor? Is anything running over a wifi network?

**Comment by [jd](https://answers.ros.org/users/2939/jd/) on 2013-03-10**:
The turtlebot has a dual intel atom 1.86Ghz processor.  The workstation I'm worried about.  It's an acer laptop with an AMD triple core at 2.1Ghz.  I've tried it on two networks both seem to give the same result.  I do have an unused router that I could use to set up a network just for turtlebot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The turtlebot processor might be a little slow for the VO. Try it with QVGA data. Post the output of your console here, and I will try to help you further.

Alternatively, you can try streaming the data out of the turltebot and runing the VO on the laptop. You might run into network issues, so again, setting to QVGA is recommended to reduce the bandwidth.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jd](https://answers.ros.org/users/2939/jd/) on 2013-03-14**:
Thanks.  I actually was testing it again today before I saw your comment so I don't have any output right now.  I connected the workstation and turtlebot directly to my router to see if the network was a problem and it works much better now.  I'll try lowering the resolution now too.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll let Ivan Dryanovski answer about the ccny package.

I would just like to say that "tf is old" is a common error : when you play your bag file, don't forget to :

1. rosparam set /use_sim_time true
2. rosbag play with the "--clock" option

For more details, please see : [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch/Tutorials/BagRecordingPlayback#Playing_back_data). This is a tutorial about kinect, but the principle is the same for others cameras.

Hope it'll helpo you,

Bests regards,

Steph

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1